# ¿Porque me da error sort en Angular?

Tags: angular

Cuando escribo la siguiente instruccion en Angular:

```
   @ViewChild(MatSort , { static: true } ) sort: MatSort;
```

Me dice:

**La propiedad "sort" no tiene inicializador y no está asignada de forma definitiva en el constructor.ts(2564)**

Este es el codigo completo:

```
export class ClienteComponent implements OnInit {
  public lst!: any;
  public columnas : string[]=["idCliente","nombreCliente","telefono","condicionIVA","cuit","deuda","direccion",'actions'];
  readonly width:string='300';


  constructor(
 
    private apiCliente : ApiclienteService,
    private dialog:MatDialog,
    public snackBar:MatSnackBar,
  ) {
 
    }
    
    @ViewChild(MatSort , { static: true } ) sort: MatSort;

  

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.getClientes();
    
  }
  getClientes(){
    this.apiCliente.getClientes().subscribe(response=>{
      this.lst = response;
     
   
    });
    
  }
  openAdd(){
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogClienteComponent,{
      width:this.width
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result=>{
      this.getClientes();
    });
  }
  openEdit(cliente:cliente){
    
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogClienteComponent,{
      width:this.width,
      data:cliente
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result=>{
      this.getClientes();
    });

  }
  delete (cliente:cliente){
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogDeleteComponent,{
      width:this.width,
      data:cliente
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result=>{
        if (result){
          this.apiCliente.delete(cliente.idCliente).subscribe(response=>{
       
              this.snackBar.open('Cliente eliminado con exito','',{
                duration:2000
              });
              this.getClientes();
            
          })
        }
    });
  }

  }
```

Lo que quiero hacer es ordenar un mat table obviamente.

Comment: Inicializala con `null`

Comment: Hola, seria asi:  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort = null; ?

Comment: puedes agregar el signo "!" en sort! así le indicas al compilador que no será nulo pero que tampoco haga problema ya que a la final no será nulo

Comment: Me funciono pero ordena erroneamente los registros..

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/489702/sort-de-angular-material-table-ordena-registros-erroneamente